# XLOOKUP Formula Issue Horizontal & vertical lookup

Tags: excel, xlookup

I am trying to pull data that has a vertical and horizontal lookup. The Vertical lookup provides the product that I'm trying to match and the horizontal lookup is for the dates. I have this lookup working across two sheets. It seems to be working okay, except that lookup for some reason pulls the value beneath the right value. This is really weird. Can someone please take a look at the formula and let me know what the issue might be?

$E59 - contains the lookup value - Forecast2 column A contains the data that would match with $E59. The main page $N$1 contains the date, and $G$4:$O$4 - in Forecast2 contains the date headers, whereas $G$5:$O$52 - contains the actual data.

My formula currently performs the lookup, but instead of bringing in the right value, it brings in the value beneath the right value. To give an example Row 5 in the Forecast2 sheet is the match that $E59 corresponds to, yet for some reason it's giving me the value from Row 6. If I then change the value of $E59 to match with what row 6's value is - the formula produces the value for row 7?

```
=XLOOKUP($E59,Forecast2!$A$4:$A$51,XLOOKUP('Main Page'!N$1,Forecast2!$G$4:$O$4,Forecast2!$G$5:$O$52))
```

Comment: Data to lookup in another tab is not a problem. While the lookup-table was a single argument in `VLOOKUP`, it is two arguments in `XLOOKUP`. Make sure that both ranges are the same size.
`=XLOOKUP($E59,Forecast2!$A$4:$A$51,XLOOKUP('Main Page'!N$1,Forecast2!$G$4:$O$4,Forecast2!$G$5:$O$52))`
 will return a `#VALUE!` Error because the `Lookup_Array` is `51` rows and the `Return_Array` is only `52` rows.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your ranges are wrong. To correct it, you need put your values in A5:A52 and then refer to A5:A52 in place of A4:A51. Hence, your formula would become
=XLOOKUP($E59,Forecast2!$A$5:$A$52,XLOOKUP('Main Page'!N$1,Forecast2!$G$4:$O$4,Forecast2!$G$5:$O$52))

Another method is apply an offset of -1 but it is always better to fix the source rather than the result.